# There is "/?i=2" in my wordpress website index url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently grabbed a host and first there was an index2.html in my htdocs root which was default index, I didn't remove that until I install wordpress in that root. then wordpress automatically made a httaccess file with following codes which is normal:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

now I realize that sometimes there is /?i=1 or /?i=2 in my general url, for example, wordpresssite.com/?i=2
this is a problem because I'm using some ad-unit system and I gave my website url to the system but it seems that the ad system bots some time redirect to "wordpresswebsite.com/?i=2" url and it does not match with the url I entered before (wordpresswebsite.com) so it's not gonna work.

now I removed the index2.html but the problem is still there.
this ?i=1 or 2 is about PHP GET parameter but how this parameter will appear.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, please update if you found any solution....

Comment: @jatinvermaI found that it is due to host providers configuration to prevent risks from bots... the best solution is to change your host or server plan to something like dedicated VPS or server to grab all configurations of the server by your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/6rhaa7/home_page_url_changing_to_i1/) on reddit with similar issue and the conclusion was:

> Most likely there are some rules at vhost level.
>
> ---- yes it's from the host, they said they cannot disable it as it's protecting me from bots.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested in removing the /?i=1 installed mostly by free host providers here's a tip.

Edit & upload the .htaccess file in root of website

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(.*)\?i=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [R=301, L]
```

Answer (score 1):

?i=1 or 2 or 3 is to protect your website from bots. Try using cloudflare for your website or use the .htaccess code to remove ? paramaters. Note that using any code to remove ?i=1 will remove all ? parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, you have to enable `mod_rewrite` first.

```
sudo a2enmod mod_rewrite
```

Then restart or reload your server for the new configuration to take place:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

(Try to find some fancy control panel option for this, if not having shell access)